# How can I use the below-intertext-sep in mathtools package?

Tags: align, mathtools

The `below-intertext-sep` in `mathtools` package doesn't work correctly.
I use this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\mathtoolsset{%
below-shortintertext-sep = 28pt,above-shortintertext-sep =1pt,
below-intertext-sep = 2pt,
above-intertext-sep =18pt
}
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\shortintertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\intertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your responsibility.
[image]

Comment: Going through the code, I see it `\l_MT_below_intertext_sep` being set, but I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: I filed a bug report to the maintainers of `mathtools`.

Comment: Peace be upon you my dear egreg.

Comment: @SH.Madadpour The bug has been fixed! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

With `mathtools` version v1.21, released 2018-01-08, the following document prints exactly like the example below, showing that the bug has been fixed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{%
  below-shortintertext-sep = 28pt,
  above-shortintertext-sep =  1pt,
  below-intertext-sep = 50pt,
  above-intertext-sep =  0pt,
}

\begin{document}

Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\shortintertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\intertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\end{document}
```

## Original answer (before the bug fix)

It's a bug in `mathtools.sty`; the definition of `\intertext` is indirect (so `\intertext` can only be used in certain places) and uses `\l_MT_above_intertext_sep` also at the end, where it should be `\l_MT_below_intertext_sep`.

```
\def\MT_intertext: {%
  \def\intertext##1{%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{%
      \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
      \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
      \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
      \vskip\l_MT_above_intertext_sep
       \vbox{\normalbaselines
         \ifdim
           \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
             \linewidth
           \else
             -\maxdimen
           \fi
         =\columnwidth
        \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \fi
        \noindent\ignorespaces##1\par}%
      \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
      \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
      \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
      \vskip\l_MT_above_intertext_sep
   }%
 }%
 \MH_let:NwN \shortintertext \shortintertext@
}
```

There is another problem: you have to state `original-intertext=false`. Here is a set of patches and the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\xpatchcmd{\MT_intertext:}
 {\l_MT_above_intertext_sep}
 {\nonexistentmacro}
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\MT_intertext:}
 {\l_MT_above_intertext_sep}
 {\l_MT_below_intertext_sep}
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\MT_intertext:}
 {\nonexistentmacro}
 {\l_MT_above_intertext_sep}
 {}{}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\mathtoolsset{%
  original-intertext=false,
  below-shortintertext-sep = 28pt,
  above-shortintertext-sep =  1pt,
  below-intertext-sep = 50pt,
  above-intertext-sep =  0pt,
}

\begin{document}

Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\shortintertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\begin{align*}
a &< b+c \\
\intertext{text text text text text text text text text text text text }
b &< a+c 
\end{align*}
Some text to separate alignments from each other and to see them
in context. Let's make it long enough to split across two lines.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Updated version is sent off to CTAN. The reason why `original-intertext=false,` is necessary for the patch is that, we internally use  `\MT_intertext:` via a `\let` construction, so unless `original-intertext=false,`, that `\let` information is never updated (should probably have used a `\def` instead of a `\let`....)

Comment: Peace be upon you my dear daleif.